# Java8 reports "cannot resolve constructor" by calling "::new"

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

In Intellij 15.0.3. and using Java8 I have a problem in using `::new`.
In particular, I have a class with a default constructor

```
public class Container{

  public Container(){}

}
```

I want to create a map from a list, as follows:

```
public class Test{
  private final Map<Key, Container> map;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    List<Key> keys=...//Init the list
     map = keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Container::new));


  }

}
```

In Intellij, `new` is red and the tooltip says `cannot resolve constructor Container`

If I do `() -> {new Container()}` I also have `cannot infer functional interface type Container`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each mapping function is supposed to accept a `Key` argument. `Function.identity()` does, but `Container::new` takes no parameters. Same thing with `() -> new Container()`. You need a one-argument lambda. An argument that you'll ignore, as it happens.

```
map = keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), key -> new Container()));
```

Answer (score -3):

it should be something like :

```
Collectors.toMap(Container::getMyUniqueField, Function.identity())
```

This will use getter for keys, and the object itself as the value, in the created hashmap.

Comment: `toMap` has two params. The first is the _keyMapper_ (so I have `Function.identity()`, the second is the _valueMapper_, which must return a new instance of the `Container` class. You are inverting key and value.

Comment: Exactly, what you want doesn't make sense